# PyAutoGUI を含むプログラムを Jupyter Notebook で実行すると module not found error

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

WinPython で Jupyter Notebook に PyAutoGUI というモジュールをインストールしたのですが、Runすると以下のエラーメッセージが表示されます。

```
module not found error:no module named 'pyautogui'
```

`!pip freeze` で確認したところ PyAutoGUI はインストールされています。

解決策があればご教示お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

`Jupyter Notebook`上では GUI が必要となるパッケージは動作しません。`pyautogui`を使うのであれば、エディタでプログラムを作成してコマンドプロンプトから実行してください。